# Best laptop battery charging strategy when already at 100%

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

For a Dell Vostro 7510 (which just says "3-Cell Battery, 56WHr (Integrated)" in the order...not sure what type it even is...) let's say its battery just reached 100% charge, but I have an hour left that I could have it plugged in before I need to leave and will be unable to charge.

Which will give me longer usage once I leave (and without killing battery quality/life longer-term)?

1. Staying plugged in until I leave
2. Unplugging and leaving it unplugged ("wasting" the final hour)
3. Unplugging it and topping up in the last 20-30 minutes or whatever my best guess is would leave it at or close to 100% before I go
4. Some other strategy

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Define 'best'. You can't have both optimum battery life **and** 100% charge every time you want it on an ad-hoc routine like that. Leaving it plugged now in gives you more today, with less life overall. Banging it up against the 100% mark constantly is not optimum strategy ever. Some machines can learn your daily routine & only take it from 80 to 100% in time for you to leave home.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I did define 'best' with my question, and you answered why that doesn't exist: "Leaving it plugged now in gives you more today, with less life overall."  That rules out my option 1, but doesn't answer whether 2 or 3 or 4 would be better.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb is to not overcharge your battery.  Keep it between the 20-80% range. Try not to let it fully go dead and on the opposite side do not always keep it fully charged.  This is better for the battery's health. When not in use, unplug it.  This will help prolong the battery's lifespan.

Comment: Nitpick: That's not overcharging. When you overcharge a battery, it catches fire. Laptop batteries have a BMS built in to prevent that.

Comment: @Dale So in other words, in the original scenario above, I've already made a mistake by getting to 100%.  Nonetheless, from there my best option would be to let it fall a chunk below 80% and try to charge it to 80% just before I leave, if I can guess well enough the right moment to do that.  Is that accurate?